# WSO2 loss APIs after changes in docker container

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager, docker-volume, api-manager

I'm having another problem using WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0: I have installed it in docker using three containers (one for APIM, one for Analytics and one for MySQL) and I replace some configuration files with my custom version (e.g. DB, server name, gateway setup...).
Both APIM and Analytics are configured to save data in the MySQL container and I am able to see changes in the DB.

The issue is that I cannot find my APIs neither in the publisher nor in the store after the container has been rebuilt. Changes in the DB persists, I can see the statistics for all my APIs and I get an error if I try to create a new API using the same name or context, but the store is always empty after a new build.

I have also tried to put both `/repository/deployment/server/synapse-config/default` and `/repository/tenants/` in two volumes and I can see the files created in `/.../default/api/` for my APIs, but I cannot figure out the issue.
Should I persists some additional directory not mentioned in the guide?

I don't want to put the whole APIM and Analytics homes in volumes if possible.

Answer (score 2):

First, check whether artifacts can be located in **Resources Browser**.

[image: Resources Browser]

If you can find the API related files, then the issue is related to indexing. 
**Do the following to re-index the artifacts in the registry:**

1. Rename the `<lastAccessTimeLocation>` element in the `<APIM_2.0.0_HOME>/repository/conf/registry.xml` file. If you use a clustered/distributed API Manager setup, change the file in the API Publisher node. For example, change the `/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime` registry path to `/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime_1`.
2. Shut down the API Manager, back up and delete the `<APIM_2.0.0_HOME>/solr` directory.
3. Finally start the API Manager.

Answer (score 1):

The Api Information resides in the DB and in the File system.(/repository/deployment/server/synapse-config/default/api) It is possible that the registry artifacts are not indexed properly. Can you try following?

1. Delete the solar directory.
2. Open registry.xml and change the following line as shown below. < lastAccessTimeLocation>/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime-1
3. Now restart the server. Server will re-index all the files again.

Also make sure the Databases are properly configured. Specially Registry mounting related configurations.

Comment: thanks, you answer helps me a lot: renaming the variable force APIM to re-index showing all my apis but in some case I need to change the variable several times. I solved the problem mounting also the <APIM_HOME>/solr/ folder as volume and using your trick to create the new index in solr/

Comment: Glad I could help.