# WSO2 Governance Registry - Solr index problems

Tags: solr, wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

We're having some problems about the assets in Publisher/Store in WSO2 using MySQL. We load our database of assets into WSO2 but not all of the assets show up in the store or publisher when queried. This also occuries when we try to get the assets using API.

But the missing assets can be found by:

- Calling the database directly
- looking them up in carbon
- using the store or publisher url with the asset id
- the governance rest api through id only

Using WSO2 database default (H2), this issue didn't happened.

After some research about this issue, we have found some solutions like "deleting solr and update registry.xml" to reindex all the assets that are missing but without success.

This question represents a lot of our issues with missing assets.

> [WSO2 Governance Not Finding All Assets in JDBC Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188295/wso2-governance-not-finding-all-assets-in-jdbc-database/47261947#47261947)

If someone went through this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see artifacts in the carbon console metadata listing area?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why the wso2 didn't sync with solr using MySQL... It needs more investigation about it

Comment: If so, I would recommend you to double check your registry mounting configuration(ex: have added MySQL data source in addition to the 'WSO2CarbonDB' data source, registry xml configuration etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all replies. We returned the database to H2 and the problem was solved. I don't know what happened to our MySQL Database, maybe was a tuning problem to sync with solr. We're gonna investigate this soon.

Sorry to late answer and thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you posted for 'WSO2 Governance Not Finding All Assets in JDBC Database' my answer was this:

I found that some entries weren't in the REG_LOG table and some dates in the REG_LOG table made entries not be indexed. The solution for this was adding to the REG_LOG table with current timestamps which forced a reindex and then the missing assets were able to be searched for in the web ui.

Basically what we did was create a script that inserted into the REG_LOG table for each asset so each would havea timestamp of NOW() in the table and would be indexed

Answer (score -1):

If you are using WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0, you can use skipCache property as mentioned in [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Distributed+Deployment+of+API+Manager). This will directly fetch data from the database.

[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Distributed+Deployment+of+API+Manager) - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Distributed+Deployment+of+API+Manager

Comment: We tried this but solved just tuning wisely to sync with solr. thanks anyway